# How to read all data in csv file

Tags: python, mysql, csv, flask, sqlalchemy

I've tried to upload csv file into database. However, when I do uploaded, it's only return the first data only into database. I want it to return every single row in the csv file but I don't know how to do it. Can someone help me?

Below is the code that I've written:

models.py

```
from app import db

class details(db.Model):
    #Columns

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    Email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique= True, nullable=False)
    Address =  db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)


    def __init__(self, Name, Email, Address):
  
        self.Name = Name
        self.Email= Email
        self.Address = Address
```

upload.py

```
from app.models import details
import csv
from io import TextIOWrapper

def uploadCSV():


    upload = request.files.get('upload') 
    csv_file = TextIOWrapper(upload, encoding='utf-8')
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')


    for data in csv_reader:
        name = data['name']
        email = data['email']
        address = data['address']


        query = details(Name = name, Email= email, Address = address)

        db.session.add(query)
        db.session.commit()

        return "upload"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the indent you show, your `return "upload"` executes on the first iteration of your loop.

Did you mean to do this, instead?

```
def uploadCSV():

    upload = request.files.get('upload') 
    csv_file = TextIOWrapper(upload, encoding='utf-8')
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    for data in csv_reader:
        name = data['name']
        email = data['email']
        address = data['address']

        query = details(Name = name, Email= email, Address = address)

        db.session.add(query)
        db.session.commit()

    return "upload"
```

Edit to add:  Do you really want to commit each row, or should you also unindent the `db.session.commit()` instruction to commit the entire dataset at the end (may perform better for you)?

Comment: I tried your suggestion to unindent the return "upload". Its do work only for a few lines around 40 but my actual data is around 400, and the error said "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 3795: invalid start byte" and the error highlight at `for data in csv_reader:` . Is it because my data was too big that the code couldn't handle?

Comment: That error is a problem with the encoding in the file, and I am pretty sure that is being thrown by `TextIOWrapper`.  Can you please look more closely at the stack trace?   Are you certain that the source CSV file is UTF-8?  Depending on where it was sourced, it might be in another localization, and there is no easy way to tell.  I am sorry I cannot help with that.

Comment: yeay. It's because the encoding and the sourced. I change it to 'cp1252', it worked

Comment: @noobCoderzz  Great news!  I guess that just leaves the question of whether you should unindent the `db.session.commit()`.  If you do move it outside the inner loop, then the load should run faster (although you may not be able to tell with only 400 rows), and any error such as the encoding problem will cause the entire load to fail (which is usually a good thing).

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer! ^^

1. I unindent the return 'upload'
2. Because I got error like "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 3795: invalid start byte". I found that I use wrong encoding. So, I changed the encoding from 'UTF-8' to 'cp1252' and it worked.

```
def uploadCSV():

    upload = request.files.get('upload') 
    csv_file = TextIOWrapper(upload, encoding='cp1252')
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    for data in csv_reader:
        name = data['name']
        email = data['email']
        address = data['address']

        query = details(Name = name, Email= email, Address = address)

        db.session.add(query)
        db.session.commit()

    return "upload"
```